# How to check out which windowing system am I using on ubuntu 22.04 in command line now?

Tags: command-line, xorg, desktop-environments, window, wayland

I've tried $GDMSESSION but it just outputs 'ubuntu.', not showing which windowing system like x11 or wayland?

How do I determine which am I using? Wayland or X11 only in 'command line' simply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Kubuntu and this works for me.

```
fred@z690-jammy:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE 
x11
```

Comment: Works in Ubuntu. Clear.

Comment: If one of the answers here solved your issue, @taehwanlegen, please take a moment and [accept it](//askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation. So I can not do upvote. I checked  'check mark.' thank you for help.